# php cannot start server with php threads

Tags: php, multithreading

When I try to run the command.

```
 php -S localhost:8000 -t public
```

It have the following message

> [Wed Aug 16 23:04:41 2017] PHP Fatal error:  The cli-server SAPI is
>   not supported by pthreads in Unknown on line 0
>
> Fatal error:  The cli-server SAPI is not supported by pthreads in
>   Unknown on line 0 [Wed Aug 16 23:04:41 2017] PHP Fatal error:  Unable
>   to start pthreads module in Unknown on line 0
>
> Fatal error:  Unable to start pthreads module in Unknown on line 0
>   peter@chaatz-hon:~/workspace/distance$ php -S localhost:8000 -t public
>   [Wed Aug 16 23:05:44 2017] PHP Fatal error:  The cli-server SAPI is
>   not supported by pthreads in Unknown on line 0
>
> Fatal error:  The cli-server SAPI is not supported by pthreads in
>   Unknown on line 0 [Wed Aug 16 23:05:44 2017] PHP Fatal error:  Unable
>   to start pthreads module in Unknown on line 0
>
> Fatal error:  Unable to start pthreads module in Unknown on line 0

What is the possible reason for that?

Comment: pthreads is not supported by Apache!

Comment: Can I remove the pthread loading now where start the php -S?

Answer (score 1):

It's because pthreads is NOT supported by apache (PHP-CGI), only by CLI version.

> **SAPI Support**
>
> pthreads v3 is restricted to operating in CLI only: I have spent many
> years trying to explain that threads in a web server just don't make
> sense, after 1,111 commits to pthreads I have realised that, my advice
> is going unheeded.
>
> So I'm promoting the advice to hard and fast fact: you can't use
> pthreads safely and sensibly anywhere but CLI.
>
> Thanks for listening ;)
>
> [Quote from GitHub: pthreads](https://github.com/krakjoe/pthreads)